# How to run Node.js index file using Supervisor in a Laravel project on a Ubuntu server?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, ubuntu, supervisord

How can I use Supervisor to automatically run the main Node.js file (index file) in my Laravel project on a server running Ubuntu?

I want to ensure that the Node.js process is continuously monitored and restarted if it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the steps given below:

**1. Install Supervisor, Node.js, and npm:**

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor

sudo apt install nodejs

sudo apt install npm
```

**2. Check Node.js and npm versions:**

```
node -v

npm -v
```

**3. Create a Supervisor config file:**

```
sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-npm.conf
```

Inside the file, add the following code:

```
[program:laravel-npm]
directory=/var/www/html   # Change to your Laravel app path
command=node index.js    # Change to your Node.js command
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-npm.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-npm.out.log
```

Save and close the file.

**4. Run Supervisor commands:**

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-npm:*
```

This setup helps Supervisor monitor and restart your Node.js process in your Laravel project on an Ubuntu server. Make sure to customize the file paths and commands according to your project.